# Wingpanel Clock Has Disappeared

Tags: wingpanel, clock

I installed Freya recently and shortly thereafter the clock disappeared.
Sometimes I can access the calendar pop-up by randomly clicking around where the clock used to be, but this doesn't always work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had uninstalled evolution* packages (I thought I didn't need them) and the time indicator dissapeared

I reinstalled it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-datetime
```

logged out and everything went fine

also check: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1377/244

Comment: This worked, allowing me to see both the time and the date/day/year etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1356698).

But I walked around it, randomly changing settings in `dconf-editor` on `com` > `canonical` > `indicator` > `datetime`.

[image]

Comment: I toggled the settings a bit, and was able to display the time, but not the date. That is, if I check `show-date` or `show-day`, the clock disappears. But at least I know the time. Thank you.

Comment: I have no datetime category in com.canonical.indicator. any idea? what shall I reinstall?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me after I uninstalled the US language in the `Region and Language` section and left only Portuguese.

After I reinstalled the US language, the clock appeared again.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to read more like an answer and less like a story :)

Comment: I went to Region and Language section and marked English (and Spanish) languages. Then logged out and issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a wingpanel clock. I tried all instructions above, but it wasn't helped.

There are processes of the indicator:

[image: https://s15.postimg.cc/9qu8rodnf/Screenshot_from_2018-08-09_23.09.53.jpg]

So, it should work. However it doesn't:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this bug?

Thanks.

**Done! This one works:**

```
sudo apt install --reinstall wingpanel-indicator-datetime
```