# Time in wingpanel disappeared

Tags: wingpanel

Since the latest update my clock disappeared.
(I guess through the latest language-plug update)

The workaround from [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1195/227) don't work.

How can I get the clock back to wingpanel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try re-installing the date-time indicator

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-datetime
```

If this doesn't work, try editing the /etc/environment file and put this line at the end of it:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Log out and log back in, and it should display your clock.

For a detailed reading:
[Launchpad-Bug-Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1356698)